# How To Display The Active Cell In Top Left In Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have large google sheet-sheet, where would be nice that active cell would come to top left corner in the sheet. I have found solution in Excel (https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5117-excel-active-cell-top-screen.html) so I have been wondered that is similar possible in google sheet? Could anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

I've updated my code to be more explicit as to how to run and test the .setActiveSelection() function.

You should be able to use the following:

```
function setActiveCellFunction() {
  var test = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  Logger.log(test);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().setActiveSelection("A1");
  var test = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  Logger.log(test);
}
```

The results from the two Logger.log() calls are as follows:

```
[19-08-05 08:54:26:287 EDT] D8
[19-08-05 08:54:26:291 EDT] A1
```

Comment: Activated cell didn't go to top left in the screen, when I used upper code... Any help or any other ideas? (e.g. If my activated cell is H16, which script I should use if I want that cell to go to top left in the sheet?)

Comment: I've updated my answer to be a bit more detailed.  You can see from the results of the logs that the Active Cell has changed.  Can you test this out and reply if there is any issue still?  (Otherwise, if you can use this answer, then please "mark as answer" :) )

Answer (score 0):

Activate a cell beyond that cell, use SpreadsheetApp.flush() to update the UI and then activate the good cell.